# Assigning variables the pop method

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, quicksort

I am tying to understand Hoan's sorting algorithm.
Here is the code:

```
import random

def qsort(a):
    if len(a) < 2:                      # if nothing to sort, return
        return
    stack = []                          # initialize stack
    stack.append([0, len(a)-1])
    while len(stack) > 0:               # loop till stack empty
        lo, hi = stack.pop()            # pop lo, hi indexes
        p = a[(lo + hi) // 2]           # pivot, any a[] except a[hi]
        i = lo - 1                      # Hoare partition
        j = hi + 1
        while(1):
            while(1):                   #  while(a[++i] < p)
                i += 1
                if(a[i] >= p):
                    break
            while(1):                   #  while(a[--j] < p)
                j -= 1
                if(a[j] <= p):
                    break
            if(i >= j):                 #  if indexes met or crossed, break
                break
            a[i],a[j] = a[j],a[i]       #  else swap elements
        if(j > lo):                     # push indexes onto stack
            stack.append([lo, j])
        j += 1
        if(hi > j):
            stack.append([j, hi])
```

It works, but I don't understand the line with lo, hi = stack.pop().
What does this mean?
Please explain what does this do, thank you!

Comment: Are you asking what `stack.pop()` does, or how the assignment works?

Comment: As far as I know stack.pop() removes the last element of list stack, but how could that be assigned to two variables?

Comment: Because the items of `stack` are lists of two elements.

Comment: Ok, so it deletes the last element (list) and assignes it's elements to the two variables?

Comment: Yeah, it works like this, I tested it, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, lo and hi are variables that are assigned the value from the last entry of the stack list. The reason two variables are used is that the pop function returns two values hence lo & hi for each